# Drag and Drop the cross sign within box in the grid using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a box of grid in an HTML in which if anyone clicks on a box it will draw x sign on it and if I click on the box which already has `x` then it will remove that `x`.

Checkout [**this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wz4hs9qa/1/).

**Problem Statement:-**

- Now I want to drag this cross sign (x) to any other grid in my box but if I am trying to drag the cross sign to a box which already has it, then the action should be cancelled.

How can I do this using HTML and plain Javascript only?

Comment: Not able to access JS bin.

Comment: Ok use this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4941cxt/) instead.

Comment: In case someone wants the JS separated from the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/wz4hs9qa/1/

Comment: @myfunkyside Thanks for the help. I will use that jsfiddle in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wz4hs9qa/2/

These are the changes to your code:

1) Gave each cell an `id` corresponding to its index:

```
cell.id = "cell_" + i;
```

2) Fixed a typo:

```
on_drop.value = "drop(event, this)";
```

3) Moved the `ondragover` attribute to the cell, not the X inside it.  This is important because dropping must be enabled on empty cells.

```
var on_dragover = document.createAttribute('ondragover');
on_dragover.value = "allowDrop(event, this)";
cell.setAttributeNode(on_dragover);
```

4)

a) Gave each X an `id` similar to that of its containing cell, so that the `drop` event handler knows which cell to clear when moving an X.

b) Set an `ondragstart` handler that stores the index into the drag-and-drop `dataTransfer` object.  This code is designed to work on both newer browsers (using a MIME type) and older versions of IE (using "text").

```
function createX(obj){
    if (obj.innerHTML == ''){
        var id = obj.id.replace("cell", "X");
        obj.innerHTML = "<h1 id='" + id + "' style='text-align:center;' draggable='true' ondragstart='saveCell(event, this);'>X</h1>";
    } else {
        obj.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function saveCell(ev, obj) {
    var cell_index = obj.id.substring(2);
    try {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", cell_index);
    } catch (exception) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", cell_index);
    }
}
```

5) Got rid of the line that cleared an X on every drop, since this is inconsistent with the behavior you want now:

```
function allowDrop(ev, obj) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //obj.innerHTML = '';
}
```

6) Added code to `drop()` that:

a) checks whether there is already an X in this cell (cancelling drop if so)

b) puts an X in this cell

c) reads the cell index from the `dataTransfer` object and uses it to clear the cell where the drag was initiated

```
function drop(ev, obj) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (obj.innerHTML !== '') { // not empty
        return false;
    } else {
        createX(obj);
    }

    var data;
    try {
        data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    } catch (exception) {
        data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    }
    var cell_id = "cell_" + data;
    document.getElementById(cell_id).innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated your help. It works fine. :) But I am seeing one minor issue. As of now default box size is 3x3 right? So cross sign is able to fit properly in each boxes. If I try to increase the box size to 8x8, cross sign doesn't gets fit in one box properly, it is getting overlap to other box. How do we tackle this situation?

Comment: This happens because the X's are wrapped in `<h1>`, which browsers display in a large font.  Use CSS to change the font size (and preferably, replace the `<h1>` with `<div>` or `<span>` before doing this).

Comment: I would use an image of an "X" (with transparent background), and scale that to the size of the clicked `gridCell`, in `createX()`. This way, the "X" will always scale in proportion to the cells.

Comment: Here, put this in createX(): `obj.innerHTML = '<img src="http://goo.gl/vmJaeZ" class="x" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)" draggable="true" />';`... And this in CSS: `.x{width:100%; height:100%;}`

Comment: @myfunkyside cool. work pretty good now :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @david I accidentally used your question's code as source. If you use the answer's code, it looks like this: `obj.innerHTML = '<img src="http://goo.gl/vmJaeZ" class="x" id="'+id+'" draggable="true" ondragstart="saveCell(event, this)" />';`